# Rails Minitest assert_equal 200 || 304

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

I use Minitest and I am wondering  if it's possible to success my tests either with 200 or 304 page.status_code.

Not sure to be clear, but I tried this:

```
assert_equal 200 || 304 ,  page.status_code
```

sounds does not work.

So there is a way to achieve this.

Thx

Comment: Can you respond with multiple statuses within a single method? I mean without AJAX interaction. Correct me if I'm wrong, just to know.

Comment: Actually I'm using Ajax and when I launch rake my tests comes in a random way and sometimes it passes or fail because I am just waiting 200 and 304 coming. So that's my question. Maybe a way to avoid this random ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from testing and digging in the docs, both `assert_equal` and `assert_response` will only take one value.

I don't know if this is recommended, but you can assert the response code is one or the other.

```
test 'should get right code' do
  get some_path
  assert status === 200 || status === 304
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this with `assert_includes(array, object)` which tests that `object` is in `array`.

In your example, this would be:

```
assert_includes [200, 304], page.status_code
```

Documentation: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_includes